# Call same method for two objects of the same class in one line

Tags: java, merge, simplify

Is it possible to call the same method for two objects in one line?

From:

```
a.roll();
b.roll();
```

To:

```
a.b.roll();
```

Comment: `a.getNum() + b.getNum();`

Comment: Yes, it is. But... what result do you expect?

Comment: I thought I'd try to limit the amount of characters used to call the exact same method for two objects of the same class.

Comment: Avoid this type of thing. When you start working in a team environment, your teammates will thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`varargs`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-arguments-varargs-in-java/) parameter to define a `rollAll()` function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments of the same type.

So your code would look like this:

```
rollAll(a, b);
```

or

```
rollAll(a, b, c, d, e);
```

The method definition for `rollAll()` would look like this:

```
void rollAll(Rollable... rollables) {
    for (Rollable r: rollables) {
        r.roll();
    }
}
```